# wp_list_authors() returning the wrong member url

Tags: templates, buddypress, bbpress, author-template, list-authors

I've recently started work on a site which includes both BuddyPress and bbPress.

When I use the `wp_list_authors()` function the list returned to me links to each author's BuddyPress profile.

Disabling BuddyPress makes `wp_list_authors()` link to the author's bbPress forum profile page.

How can I ensure that `wp_list_authors()` returns links to each author's standard author pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code of `wp_list_authors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/) you will see that the link is generated by a call to [`get_author_posts_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/). The latter has a filter that allows for modification of the url. So, you would have to find the filters in BuddyPress and bbPress and [remove them](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/).